# How to change layout colour on java by hex?

Tags: java, android, layout, colors, hex

I want to change layout colour according to users answer. There is an EditText on screen. When user write a hex code in there, background color turns to users code.

```
EditText hex;
Button ok;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hex);
      // User writes like that "#232323"

    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);


    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener){
      //I want to make background that code
    }




}
```

How can I make that?

Comment: What is ID of parent element in the XML?

Comment: RelativeLayout id is layout on xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditText hex;
Button ok;
RelativeLayout baselayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.hex);
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    baseLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
           {
            String colorString=hex.getText().toString();

           //Validate Color before setting
            try {
                Color filteredColor = Color.parseColor(colorString);
                baseLayout.setBackgroundColor(filteredColor);
                } 
           catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                // This color string is not valid
                }            
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help 